# UItextView and back space click event on keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to detect which character is removed on back space click event on keyboard in `UITextView`.

So if anybody knows solution please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am searching for solution but didn't find any so if you have any please help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should implement the protocol UITextViewDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

and just get the text in range
try this to have a log (it's empty in case it's not a replacement but a new input)

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {


        NSLog(@"deleting this string: |%@|", [textView.text substringWithRange:range]);


    return YES;
}
```

ps

remember to set your class as the delegate of your UITextView

Comment: sorry i didn't understand i just want to detect which character is removed on back space in keyboard...
'Text' return new replacement char right not deleted character..

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you want. This method detects whenever a character is removed, and prints it to the console.

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *textField;
    NSString *currentText;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textField  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 30)];
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}

-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)sender{

    if (!currentText) {
        currentText = sender.text;
    }

    if (![currentText isEqualToString:sender.text]) {

        //The text that is in the textField at the moment is shorter than it was the last time the textfield was editted... This shows that a backspace was pressed
        if (currentText.length > sender.text.length) {


            NSLog(@"Character: %@", [currentText substringFromIndex:sender.text.length]);

        }



    }

    currentText = sender.text;


}


@end
```